# Where is an equivalent polyfit function in opencv 3?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to fit a curve using a second-order polynomial for the purpose of lane detection using openCV and C++. In openCV 2 there was a polyfit function that was able to accomplish this, but in openCV 3 the function seems to have been removed, and I haven't been able to find an equivalent that would have replaced it. Is there a decent way to get around this issue? (besides going back to openCV 2).

Comment: To improve your question, I'd add information regarding how you use to do it in the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have access to older files used in opencv. Just add this file to your project:

http://code.opencv.org/attachments/438/polyfit.cpp

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I ended up doing.